# Compare the values in two tables and insert into the second table the value fetched from the first table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, arraylist

Pls Help!
I've 2 tables: Info and Message
Info has columns as :

```
id  name   location   description  from
1    abc    def         ghijg      123
2    xyz    wqk        fdgbf       234
3    tuv    ghn        hndBD       345
```

Message had columns as :

```
id   text     from          created_at
1    HI        123             12345
1    hey       123             12345
2    hello     234             98765
```

I want to insert new values into Message and set the value of id(in Message) with the corresponding value of id of Info. As the example shows id 1 in message tells us that this row corresponds to the Info table's id 1.

I'm writing Java code to insert the new values into Message.

My tables are huge so I'm storing the id and name from Info into an ArrayList and then comparing the id from the ArrayList and some name values are null. Im using a for loop for iterating through the ArrayList and then compare the name value with another name value which im calling from twitter and insert into Message.
the code is:

```
for(Bank v: bankid){   
    if(v.getName()== null || v.getName().equals(Name)){
        if(v.getName().equals(Name)){
            System.out.println(v.getId());
            ps.setString(1,v.getId());
        }
    }
}
```

Insert the id value fetched from the Info Table into Message along with the other values.

I'm unable to insert any new values. How do i do that?
I'm using this statement:

```
 String sql = "INSERT INTO MESSAGE(ID,text,from,craeted_at) VALUES (ID,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
```

Please help!
thanks!

Comment: I don't even see any question marks.

Comment: I cant see the question but what i can see some NPE cause and re execute same condition -- `if(v.getName()!= null && v.getName().equals(Name)){...}`

Answer (score 0):

First of all-

```
if(v.getName()== null || v.getName().equals(Name))
```

this line can give you **null pointer exception**. So change the check as

```
if(v.getName()!= null || Name.equals(v.getName()))
```

then to insert the values from prepared statement Ex.

```
      ps.setInt(1,23);
      ps.setString(2,"Roshan");
      ps.setString(3, "CEO");
      ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Thank you! This works for running the loop once, but i want to insert the values for each id, run it a number of times and insert each time into the table. how to do that?

Comment: For that use for loop.